# PyQt - QAbstractScrollArea to get scroll location

Tags: pyqt

Is there a way in PyQt, for `QAbstractScrollArea` to get the current scroll location?

I'd like to save the current scroll location so that next time I reload the entire window (with new data), I'd automatically scroll to the "saved" scroll location.

Here is my full code.

First, I have a `QTableView` that inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea`

```
tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
```

I load it with data, and then draw the GUI.

```
tableView.setModel(some_model)
```

So far, so good.

But eventually, I refresh the entire GUI with new data.

```
def draw():
    tableView.setModel(refreshed_model)
```

If this is all I do, when I refresh the view, it automatically just display the view without any scroll, essentially bringing my view back to the beginning.

I was hoping for something like the following

```
def draw():
    savedPos = tableView.verticalScrollBar().getCurrentPosition() # doesn't exist
    tableView.setModel(refreshed_model)
    tableView.verticalScrollBar().setCurrentPosition(savedPos)
```

Meaning if I was scrolled to the bottom right before the refresh, and then I refresh, I'd actually automatically scroll to the bottom. Essentially "saving" my place

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: use `tableView.verticalScrollBar().value()` and  `tableView.verticalScrollBar().setValue()`

Comment: yes that works. thank you